# JSONException while loading Integrated youtube channel videos

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, youtube

I have integrated youtube channel in my app but it doesn't show all videos..For some channels it shows only very few videos..If I put `throw new RuntimeException(e);`while catching JSONException app crashes and shows following errors-

```
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.SoundcloudActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(SoundcloudActivity.java:223)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.SoundcloudActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(SoundcloudActivity.java:1)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    ... 5 more
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.SoundcloudActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(SoundcloudActivity.java:191)
11-02 20:00:40.868: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    ... 8 more
11-02 20:00:40.952: E/AppErrorDialog(348): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
11-02 20:00:41.476: E/WindowManager(15351): Activity com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.SoundcloudActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41929000 that was originally added here
11-02 20:00:41.476: E/WindowManager(15351): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.SoundcloudActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41929000 that was originally added here
11-02 20:00:41.476: E/WindowManager(15351):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
11-02 20:00:41.476: E/WindowManager(15351):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:294)
11-02 20:00:41.476: E/WindowManager(15351):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
```

This is the channel i am trying to integrate-

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/BeingIndianchannel
```

It only shows latest three videos
Here is the code-

```
    ArrayList<Channel> actorsList;
    //private static String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=xyz&channelId=UCdf6i1jTJl0TLzXc1KMDMKA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20";
    String videoid;
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
    private static final String TAG_KIND = "kind";
    private static final String TAG_ETAG = "etag";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_KINDV = "kind";
    private static final String TAG_VIDEOID = "videoId";
    private static final String TAG_SNIPPET = "snippet";
    private static final String TAG_PUBLISHED = "publishedAt";
    private static final String TAG_CHANNELID = "channelId";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_THUMBNAILS = "thumbnails";
    private static final String TAG_DEFAULT = "default";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_MEDIUM = "medium";
    private static final String TAG_URL2 = "url";
    private static final String TAG_HIGH = "high";
    private static final String TAG_URL3 = "url";
    private static final String TAG_CHANNEL = "channelTitle";
    private static final String TAG_BROADCAST = "liveBroadcastContent";
    ChannelAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtubevidlist);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Channel>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=xyz&channelId=UChAlpEbfW1y9auiBC08ZwGQ&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20");
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ChannelAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String name = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.name_label))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        YoutubeActivity2.class);

                in.putExtra("TAG_VIDEOID", name);

                startActivity(in);
;               
            }
        });
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(SoundcloudActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Channel actor = new Channel();

                        actor.setKind(c.getString(TAG_KIND));
                        actor.setEtag(c.getString(TAG_ETAG));
                        JSONObject id = c.getJSONObject(TAG_ID);
                        actor.setKind2(id.getString(TAG_KINDV));
                        actor.setVideoid(id.getString(TAG_VIDEOID));

                        JSONObject snippet = c.getJSONObject(TAG_SNIPPET);
                        actor.setPublished(snippet.getString(TAG_PUBLISHED));
                        actor.setChannelid(snippet.getString(TAG_CHANNELID));
                        actor.setTitle(snippet.getString(TAG_TITLE));
                        actor.setDescription(snippet.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                        JSONObject thumbnail = snippet.getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAILS);
                        JSONObject defaul = thumbnail.getJSONObject(TAG_DEFAULT);
                        actor.setUri1(defaul.getString(TAG_URL));
                        JSONObject medium = thumbnail.getJSONObject(TAG_MEDIUM);
                        actor.setUri2(medium.getString(TAG_URL2));
                        JSONObject high = thumbnail.getJSONObject(TAG_HIGH);
                        actor.setUri3(high.getString(TAG_URL3));
                        actor.setChannel(snippet.getString(TAG_CHANNEL));
                        actor.setBroadcast(snippet.getString(TAG_BROADCAST));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("exception","ParseException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("exception","IOException");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
```

According to [the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search):

> If the id.type property's value is youtube#video, then this property will be present and its value will contain the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify a video that matches the search query.

`videoId` is an optional value. You need to use `JSONObject.has()` to check if it exists before calling `JSONObject.getString()`.

Comment: if  videoid is not there for any video then how will it be uniquely identify..nd how can i play tht video?

Comment: You are either going to get a `videoId`, a `channelId` _or_ a `playlistId`. You are not always going to get only a video back in a search query.